# PHP - Sort Indexed Array by even elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in PHP. The array is names in the even indices and times (MM:SS.XX).

```
Array ( [0] => Emma Hogan [1] => 09:12.55 [2] => Bob Harrison [3] => 12:00.15 [4] => Dave Haenze [5] => 10:00.98 [6] => Tau Newman [7] => 07:05.15 [8] => Cai Jones [9] => 44:15.59 )
```

What I want it to do is grab the every other element (the times) and sort the array by shortest time to longest. My code for it looks like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<$arrlength;$i+=2) {
    $j = $i;
    while (($j>0)&&($array[($j-2)] > $array[$j])){
        $temp = $array[$j];
        $array[$j] = $array[($j-2)];
        $array[($j-2)] = $temp;
        $temp2 = $array[($j+1)];
        $array[($j+1)] = $array[($j-1)];
        $array[($j-1)] = $temp;
        $j = $j - 2;
    }
}
```

However, the output it returns looks like this:

```
Emma Hogan
07:05.15
07:05.15
09:12.55
Bob Harrison
10:00.98
10:00.98
12:00.15
Dave Haenze
44:15.59
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change to make it sort properly?

Comment: Why are you doing that in the first place? Use two different arrays instead, don't put names and times in the same array.

Comment: if you had two differenr arrays as @DanyCaissy suggests, you could then use something like `array_multisort` http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: OK. If I had two different arrays, once with only times, the other with only names, how would I sort them? Would array_multisort do it on its own?

Comment: Just have either the times or names as the index of your array and the other as the value.  Then just use `sort` or `ksort`, done.

Comment: I managed to change it to an associative array and sort it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've indicated that you can change the array format.  If so consider the following:

```
$array = array ( 'Emma Hogan' => '09:12.55' );
asort($array);  //or arsort()
```

Or:

```
$array = array ( '09:12.55' => 'Emma Hogan' );
ksort($array);  //or krsort()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your array layout makes little sense for what you want to accomplish. I sugest   fixing that first, instead of bending the head and trying to work on bad data structure. I.e.:

```
$tmp = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($srcArray); $i+=2) {
   $tmp[$srcArray[i]] = $srcArray[$i+1];
}
```

and then you can sort `$tmp` using [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.usort.php). Or even better, you can convert your times to numeric value and then just user ordinary sort() to do the job.